# Composer install cannot delete files

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-forge

I am attempting to run a composer install to update dependencies on my production server, but I continue to get the following error (this happens to be on a Laravel Forge deployed server).

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 24 removals
  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (v3.2.1)

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /home/forge/website.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/composer.json:
```

Why is this happening? Can I manually delete the entire vendor folder on the forge server and redeploy all the dependencies without harming it?

Comment: For people on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227303/470749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a permission problem. Maybe at some point you used `sudo` and the files now are owned by `root`. If you usually use another user for this operation and now use that one again, the files of course cannot be removed.

So try

```
ls -l /home/forge/website.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/composer.json
```

to see which user/group owns the file. Also check the permissions of that directory; maybe it is not writeable anymore?

Comment: Looks like this was the problem. I had to use `sudo` to delete the files in the vendor folder.

Answer (score 5):

The problem might be because composer is hitting its timeout. So you might be need increase the time out of composer.

You could take the following measures to gain some speed:

1. Increase composer process-timeout (default 300) (not really needed if the following settings will help you gain speed, but can't hurt)
2. Set dist as preferred install type.
3. Enable https protocol for github, which is faster.

   ```
   ~/.composer/config.json
        {
         "config": {
                   "process-timeout":      600,
                   "preferred-install":    "dist",
                   "github-protocols":     ["https"]
                    }
                 }
   ```

If you still have problems after that, you can also clear composer's cache:

```
 rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```

Also you might try updating git.

Similar question is discussed [Here in laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/install-composer-dependencies-fails-during-install-repository-with-runtimeexception)

Comment: I don't think its a timeout. The link you provided seems to have a different error message that refers to permissions. This error message is produced immediately, not after 300 seconds. I deleted the composer cache as well with no effect. Can I `rm -rf vendor` without causing an issue?

Comment: Well, in the end, I did a `rm -rf vendor` and ran `composer install` and that cleared up my problem.

Comment: Maybe you have had changed a something from the vendor folder

Answer (score 2):

Just update your composer version

```sh
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of permission problem, Maybe you used sudo for composer update or composer install. Run:

```
sudo chown -R user:group projectfolder
```

or simply own the vendor folder

```
sudo chown -R user:group projectfolder/vendor
```