# Directory name must not be empty

Tags: php, symfony, exception, composer-php

I got the below error when i tried to run `composer update`
I tried to do `composer clear` and that didn't help. Works on my local windows machine but doesnt work i deploy it to a centos machine. I'n not running laravel, just composer.

My composer.json file:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "/",
      "App\\includes\\": "/includes/"

    },"classmap": [
      "/",
      "includes/"
    ]
  },
  "require": {
    "gebn/brush": "^1.1",
    "rap2hpoutre/similar-text-finder": "^1.0",
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^7.2"
  }
}
```

Error log via -v

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:52
 RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:52
 Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:809
 Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder->searchInDirectory() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:682
 Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder->getIterator() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:80
 Composer\Autoload\ClassMapGenerator::createMap() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:336
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->generateClassMap() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:319
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->addClassMapCode() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:266
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->dump() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:303
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:162
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:254
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:103
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:56
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

Comment: Please follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26216954/1193179

Comment: You put `"/"`, which usually means 'root of the filesystem'. If you meant 'the current directory', try `"./"`.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem before and the solution is some files were missing from the application they're deleted "I do not know how they are deleted lol" but I compared my current project with the previous one, and I figured out that the config folder is missing, then I copied the config from the previous project and the problem solved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.