# Install of kylekatarnls/update-helper failed

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5.6, homestead

I'm new to laravel & homestead, im currently trying to create a new project using this command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.6.*"` but i encountered this error

```
  - Removing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.2.1)
    Install of kylekatarnls/update-helper failed


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /home/vagrant/code/project2/vendor/kylekatarnls/update-helper/src:
```

when i tried to do so. I have tried solutions given by other post such as

- `composer global require kylekatarnls/update-helper` (this just repeat the errors above)
- `composer install` (this just repeat the errors above)
- `composer update --prefer-source` (this would run, but it would cause another error `reflectionParameters`)
- `composer dump-autoload` (same for this one as well)
- `composer install --no-plugins`(this one leads to more error for me related to `reflectionParameters` errors, so i would like to avoid using that.)

Currenty using `laravel 5.6.*` and Php version is `7.1.3`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried to delete that folder by hand?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, i tried to delete vendor and tried `install composer` after, none seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

try this command is upgrading from version 8.0.0 of the vagrant box to 8.0.1 solved this for me So in the homestead folder run.

vagrant box update

Comment: laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#updating-homestead

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using NFS. There is a known issue for the VirtualBox
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18776

The issue still around for VirtualBox 6.1.18

Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63139337/9104189

Using NFS basically resolve all the share folder performance issue and resolve all the weird "Could not delete xxx" issue

Install the NFS plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

Update your `Homestead.yaml`

```
...

folders:
    - map: C:\<your code folder>
      to: /home/vagrant/code
      type: "nfs"
...
```

If you are using Windows, try this
https://dogcomp.medium.com/install-laravel-8-x-on-win-10-with-homestead-virtualbox-ec996f9a2cb6

Answer (score 0):

I WAS FACING THIS ISSUE

Problem 1
- kylekatarnls/update-helper is locked to version 1.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
- kylekatarnls/update-helper 1.1.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
Problem 2
- kylekatarnls/update-helper 1.1.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- nesbot/carbon 1.39.0 requires kylekatarnls/update-helper ^1.1 -> satisfiable by kylekatarnls/update-helper[1.1.1].
- nesbot/carbon is locked to version 1.39.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

I searched for hours on google then what worked for me is the package was locked for composer version 1.^ and on my local I had 2.^ installed.

I have down graded my composer by this
command = composer self-update --1

Hope it was helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).